# Sum elements of list of list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have multiple lists of elements which have a date and a value.

firstList has (for example) :

```
01/01/2013 , 100

02/01/2013 , 444

03/01/2013 , 357

.
.
.
```

Others lists have more dates and others values

And I add each list in a `List<List<myElements>> myListOfLists;`

Now, how should I do to have 1 resulting list which contains the sum of all values for each date ?

Thanks,

Comment: May I know why I got a down vote please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the definition of myElement is like the following:

```
public class Item
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Amount {get; set; }
}
```

Then your initial list would be of type `List<List<Item>>`. You can take the sum of Amounts on the same dates, if you flatten your initial list, like below:

```
List<Item> result = myListOfLists.SelectMany(x => x)
                                   .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                                   .Select(grp => new Item
                                   { 
                                       Date = grp.Key, 
                                       Amount = grp.Sum(y => y.Amount)
                                   }).ToList();
```

[Here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/nce85e) is the link of the test of provided solution.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to *flatten* your list of lists into a single list, then *group by* the date, then *sum* each group.

You didn't show any code, but it should be something along:

```
var result = yourListOfLists.SelectMany(x => x)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.TheDateProperty)
                            .Select(grp => new {key = grp.Key, 
                                                sum = grp.Sum(e => e.TheNumber)});
```